# File.Create is creating a folder instand of file

Tags: c#

I'm writing a function which is going to serialize class and save it to file, some classes must be saved in a different folder. I'm using Unity and C#. Here's my code:

```
    public void save<T>(T data, string fileName) where T : class{
    if (fileName == "")
        Debug.Log ("Empty file path");
    FileStream file = null;
    try{
        if(fileName.IndexOf("/") > 0){
            string[] strDirName = fileName.Split(new char[]  {'/'});
            string dirName = strDirName[0];
            if(!Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + dirName)){
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + dirName);
            }
        }
        file = File.Create(constructFilePath(fileName));
        string a = constructFilePath(fileName);
        binFormatter.Serialize(file, data);
        Debug.Log ("File saved succesfully" + fileName);
    }catch(IOException e){
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }finally{
        if(file != null)
            file.Close();
    }
}

string constructFilePath(string fileName){
    return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName);
}
```

I have no idea why it's saving files as folder, this happens since I added this line to construct constructFilePath

```
if(fileName[0] != "/")
    fileName = "/" + fileName;
```

But without this file it's creating different folder. It's concatenating the Application.persistentDataPath with the folder name and creates the file there
so if my persistentDataPath  = C:/Users/User/AppData/LocalLow/DefaultCompany/TestGame and I want to store the file inside this folder in folder a and store file b in it

```
C:/Users/User/AppData/LocalLow/DefaultCompany/TestGame/a/b
```

it creates folder with name TestGamea and stores b inside it

```
 C:/Users/User/AppData/LocalLow/DefaultCompany/TestGamea/b
```

Comment: You can use Path.Combine instead of your own constructFilePath.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` which will handle leading and trailing slashes for you, e.g. `Path.Combine("C:\My\Path\", "\my\file.txt")` results in `C:\My\Path\my\file.txt`

Comment: Guys thank you, but now it's only adding a / before the file name, any ideas why?

Comment: Update the code with current implementation.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are evaluating one thing and performing something different here:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + dirName)){
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + dirName);
            }
```

Change this to:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, dirName))){
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, dirName));
            }
```

Like Eric said, use Path.Combine.  it will reliably combine path parts and ensure you get the same result every time so you don't have to worry about string manipulation.